# Definite integral of a function with finite $x$ such that $f(x)>\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Hi I'm having a little bit of difficulty in proving the following:

$f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is non-negative and for every $\gamma>0$, the set of points $\mathcal{X}=\{x\in[a,b]|f(x)>\gamma\}$ is finite. In other words, $|\mathcal{X}|=n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$. Show that $\int_a^b f =0$. Is there any relationship between $n$ and $\gamma$?

How could this be done using the upper and lower Riemann sums? I've tried drawing out a picture of this and I can't seem to figure out how to construct such a function, unless this is just the zero function, or with certain values of $x\in[a,b]$ such that there are only $n$ of them such that $f(x)>0$ (so removing a finite amount of elements from the image of $f$).

For the second part, the only relationship I can observe between $n$ and $\gamma$ is that obviously as $\gamma$ increases $n$ decreases, and we must have that $\max\{\mathcal{X}\}$ exists since it is finite and clearly for some $\gamma>\gamma'$, we will have that $n=0$, since $\mathcal{X}$ has to eventually be $\emptyset$.

I believe my intuition behind this is correct? But I'm at a loss as to where to even begin beyond what I described above (which is definitely not rigorous at all).

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Best,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Let $\chi_{\varepsilon} = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be the finite set of points where $f > \varepsilon$. Let $P$ be a partition of $[a, b]$ where each $x_i$ is covered with an interval of length $\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{n}$. Let $M > 0$ be a constant that bounds $f$ on $[a, b]$, e.g. $M = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}f(x_i)$. Then
\begin{align}
U(f, P) &\leq nM\frac{\varepsilon}{n} + \varepsilon(b - a) \\
&= (M + (b - a))\varepsilon.
\end{align}
Hence $U(f) \leq U(f, P) \leq (M + (b - a))\varepsilon$. Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives $U(f) \leq 0$. Since $f \geq 0$, $U(f) \geq 0$. Thus $U(f) = 0$.